# Need to find the number of rows with the same value for a column element in a CSV file

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

```
row_hash,source,agency_name,agency_ori,agency_incident_id,occurred_date
MDBPD0000-C419771020-01-01,BALTIMORE-MAIN,BALTIMORE-PD,MDBPD0000,17V0351,2017-07-26
MDBPD0000-B63BECA76C-01-01,BALTIMORE-MAIN,BALTIMORE-PD,MDBPD0000,17H0198,2017-07-26
```

This is what my CSV file looks like. I need to count the number of rows with the same 'source' column values, like BALTIMORE-MAIN = 2, ALABAMA-MAIN = 4 and so on depending on the CSV file. I'm using D3 and ReactJS (react-d3-library, d3 v3) so would appreciate any help with the code for the same.

Code for the App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './data';
import { Layout } from 'antd';
import View1 from './views/View1';
import View2 from './views/View2';
import View3 from './views/View3';
import View4 from './views/View4';
import View5 from './views/View5';
import View6 from './views/View6';
import './dashboard.css';

const { Sider, Content } = Layout;

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedPoliceData: data[0],
            greaterThan: 0,
            includedAreas: ['Non-fatal Shooting', 'Aggravated (Assault/Battery)','Domestic Abuse','Murder (Degree unspecified)','Homicide'],
        }
    }

    changeSelectPolice = value => {
        this.setState({
            selectedPoliceData: value
        })
    }

    changeGreaterThan = value => {
        this.setState({
            greaterThan: value
        })
    }

    changeIncludedAreas = value => {
        this.setState({
            includedAreas: value
        })
    }

    render() {

        const {selectedPoliceData, greaterThan, includedAreas} = this.state;
        const filteredData = data.filter(entry=>includedAreas.indexOf(entry.crime)!==-1)
                                 .filter(entry=>entry.crimes>greaterThan);
        return (
            <div>
                <Layout style={{ height: 920 }}>
                    <Sider width={300} style={{backgroundColor:'#eee'}}>
                        <Content style={{ height: 200 }}>
                            <View1 user={selectedPoliceData}/>
                        </Content>
                        <Content style={{ height: 400 }}>
                            <View2 data={filteredData}/>
                        </Content>
                        <Content style={{ height: 400 }}>
                            <View3 
                                changeGreaterThan={this.changeGreaterThan}
                                changeIncludedAreas={this.changeIncludedAreas}
                            />
                        </Content>
                    </Sider>
                    <Layout>
                        <Content style={{ height: 300 }}>
                            <View4 data={selectedPoliceData}/>
                        </Content>
                        <Layout style={{ height: 600 }}>
                            <Content>
                                <View5 data={filteredData}/>
                            </Content>
                            <Sider width={300} style={{backgroundColor:'#eee'}}>
                                <View6 data={filteredData} changeSelectPolice={this.changeSelectPolice}/>
                            </Sider>
                        </Layout>
                    </Layout>
                </Layout>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `d3.rollup` or `d3.rollups` (d3 v6).  Something like:

```
d3.csv("csv_file.csv").then(function(data) {
    var count_by_source = d3.rollup(data, v => v.length, d => d.source);
});
```

**EDIT**: After clarification, it became clear that `react-d3-library` is being used, which is no longer maintained since several years ago.  Below are the answers for older versions of d3, but I would recommend that you load d3 directly in your html, or `npm install d3`, rather than this React wrapper.

For d3 v5, there is `d3.nest` which is a little different.

```
d3.csv("csv_file.csv").then(function(data) {
    var count_by_source = d3.nest().key(d => d.source)
        .rollup(v => v.length)
        .entries(data);
});
```

For d3 v4 or older, the `d3.csv` function was different from the current version.

```
d3.csv("csv_file.csv", function(data) {
    var count_by_source = d3.nest().key(d => d.source)
        .rollup(v => v.length)
        .entries(data);
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
data = [{
  "row_hash": "MDBPD0000-C419771020-01-01",
  "source": "BALTIMORE-MAIN",
  "agency_name": "BALTIMORE-PD",
  "agency_ori": "MDBPD0000",
  "agency_incident_id": "17V0351",
  "occurred_date": "2017-07-26"
}, {
  "row_hash": "MDBPD0000-B63BECA76C-01-01",
  "source": "BALTIMORE-MAIN",
  "agency_name": "BALTIMORE-PD",
  "agency_ori": "MDBPD0000",
  "agency_incident_id": "17H0198",
  "occurred_date": "2017-07-26"
}, {
  "row_hash": "MDBPD0000-B63BECA76C-01-01",
  "source": "ALABAMA_MAIN",
  "agency_name": "BALTIMORE-PD",
  "agency_ori": "MDBPD0000",
  "agency_incident_id": "17H0198",
  "occurred_date": "2017-07-26"
}, {
  "row_hash": "MDBPD0000-B63BECA76C-01-01",
  "source": "ALABAMA_MAIN",
  "agency_name": "BALTIMORE-PD",
  "agency_ori": "MDBPD0000",
  "agency_incident_id": "17H0198",
  "occurred_date": "2017-07-26"
}, {
  "row_hash": "MDBPD0000-B63BECA76C-01-01",
  "source": "ALABAMA_MAIN",
  "agency_name": "BALTIMORE-PD",
  "agency_ori": "MDBPD0000",
  "agency_incident_id": "17H0198",
  "occurred_date": "2017-07-26"
}, {
  "row_hash": "MDBPD0000-B63BECA76C-01-01",
  "source": "ALABAMA_MAIN",
  "agency_name": "BALTIMORE-PD",
  "agency_ori": "MDBPD0000",
  "agency_incident_id": "17H0198",
  "occurred_date": "2017-07-26"
}]

var count_by_source = d3.nest().key(d => d.source)
  .rollup(v => v.length)
  .entries(data);
console.log(count_by_source)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason it says rollup is not exported from d3

Comment: @Samarth Are you maybe using an old version of d3? Rollup is only available in v6. If so, let us know if `d3.nest` doesn't work either.

Comment: Well it only says rollup isn't exported. I'll try installing a newer version of D3

Comment: I'm actually using it with React so can't find a good way to get the latest version.

Comment: Are you using `react-d3-library`?  According to the [package.json](https://github.com/react-d3-library/react-d3-library/blob/master/package.json) this is still at v3, hasn't been updated in a while.  Try `d3.nest` the second part of my answer.

Comment: I'm actually getting this wierd error when I do that - TypeError: d3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.csv(...).then is not a function

Comment: @Samarth Looked at the [old d3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md), and updated my answer. Let us know if that works?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but its actually giving me the wrong value, when I check it in console log.

Comment: @Samarth Can you add your code to your question so we can review what is going wrong on your end?

Comment: I have added it. I was trying the d3 snippet in render before return.

Comment: @Samarth at first glance this looks fine, but I can't see how you imported the d3 library or wrote the code, nor can I reproduce what result you are seeing in console.log, if you could show us that?

Comment: I'm actually using d3 in the other components.